# How to run a JUnit test for 2 different devices on Appium?

Tags: java, android, selenium, junit, appium

I wanted to know how to run a JUnit test which can target 2 different devices?

I see you can setup Appium to target a device and set the port for that Appium server but how do you get JUnit to test the 2 different devices?

Setup for Appium on device (32456 and 43364):

```
node . -p 4492 -bp 2251 -U 32456

node . -p 4491 -bp 2252 -U 43364
```

This will run 2 Appium servers with different ports.

Inside my JUnit test I have the setup for the AndroidDriver with the port.  How are you able to test 2 different devices with the same junit test?

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

We are unable to have 2 sets of drivers within the JUnit code to different ports

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

driver2 = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4724/wd/hub"), cap);
```

This is not possible as we may not always know the different device ports.  We essentially need to have the JUnit test work of either a configurable port that we can pass into the test (not sure if this is possible).

Is it possible to pass a value into the JUnit test?  We are using JUnitCore for testing.

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:"+ SOME_PASSED_IN_PORT + "/wd/hub"), cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating multiple drivers being one of the solution

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

is equivalent to

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + "4723" + /wd/hub"), cap);
```

So you can in one naive way create and use two different drivers simultaneously as -

```
String port1 = "4491"; //assuming this being the port number
String port2 = "4492";
driver1 = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + port1 + "/wd/hub"), cap);
driver2 = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + port2 + "/wd/hub"), cap); //also the cap could differ in both the cases
```

***Note*** :  You can provide different/similar capabilities to the driver depending on your requirement. Also this is a very naive method of doing parallel execution, try and seek solution using `Selenium-Grid` for the same to get an efficient approach.

Comment: Yes I had tried that but I should have specified that this is not possible as we may not always know the different device ports.  We essentially need to have the JUnit test work of either a configurable port that we can pass into the test (not sure if this is possible).  Maybe we will need to make another server to hit which controls which appium instance.  I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Selenium Grid**

Selenium-Grid allows you run your tests on different devices in parallel. That is, running multiple tests at the same time against different devices. Essentially, Selenium-Grid support distributed test execution. It allows for running your tests in a distributed test execution environment.

Comment: Does Selenium Grid allow you to have a Junit test and run it for different devices?  How does it setup the capibilities inside the etst for Appium which has driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is you start two appium servers with different ports and update the port numbers in the script , but u need to replicate the code , other solution is use selenium grid

Comment: 2 different ports is not an option as stated in the question.